# Combining 2 PHP scripts

Tags: php, html

I have 2 web pages. Both have PHP scripts. Playing.php has a table showing the last 20 songs played on my shoutcast server. I'm trying to get that displayed on my index page.

Index.html: http://www.deamon.org

The page I'm trying to add is

http://www.deamon.org/scxml/playing.php

Can I do this with include function and echo or is there a better way.

Comment: I find there's more control using an `include`, but that's just "me". If you ever want to add more code in your include, you won't work as hard. If you're planning on showing a file from a different server, well, that's different ball of twine altogether. iframes can be a pain (*in the neck*), what with having to control width and height etc.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way is to use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.deamon.org/scxml/playing.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks of all the help. I'm going to try iframe and see if that works.

Comment: So the iframe worked but it doesn't show on my iphone. Viewing the page without being in iframe works fine. Does it need to be in a div ? The page starts to load then just shows a black page. Here is my page. http://www.deamon.org

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would simply be to include it with a simple include statement or using an iframe

```
<?php include("link to file"); ?>
<iframe src="link to file"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to include the .php file into your index page. However including PHP code into an HTML type page requires reconfiguring your server. Instead, do the following:

- Change your `index.html` file to an `index.php` file. It will be read and rendered the same way without requiring any changes. (make sure that the `index.html` file doesn't exist on the server so that the `index.php` file automatically gets picked up
- add the following line of code into your `index.php` file:

  ```
  <?php include('path/to/playing.php'); ?>
  ```

Comment: Have you read [`the manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)? This isn't an `iframe` it's an [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). This will fail.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to get at. How/why would this fail? I've used this type of include in my php files before, and it's worked...

Comment: include is for a file and not an `http` call

Comment: Example 3 on the page you linked me to shows that http files will work. However, you're right. It might not be good practice to ask for http, so instead, use the relative path to the files instead.

Comment: I tend to think that you can probably use `http://...` "IF" it's on your own server, but I know for a fact that you can't use it if it's coming from another. **EDIT:** I just tried it on my server, and both did not work; a file from my server and a pointer to another while using `http://www.example.com/file.php` as an example.

Comment: I know you can't go it from other people's servers, however the OP seems to be doing it from his own server. You may need to toggle a setting or two like allow_url_include, which is why it's probably better to use relative paths.

Comment: You're probably right. I haven't checked what my `allow_url_include` is set at.

Comment: Haha, anyway thanks for an interesting discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP include you can do this by adding this line of code into the index file.

First you would have rename index.html to index.php and then place the following code in-between the  tags where you would like the page displayed.

```
<?php include '/scxml/playing.php'; ?>
```